# What is the Free Boundary Conditions?

Tags: boundary-conditions, lattice-model, qft-in-curved-spacetime

I'm studying a paper given here 
[click for the paper.](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.00716.pdf)
This is a paper about Lattice Field Theory in curved spacetime.
In Lattice simulations one usually uses periodic boundary conditions in every directions.
But here the guys use something called "the free boundary conditions" in some direction.
I'm confused at what the free boundary conditions are.

Anyone have any opinion?

Comment: I know nothing about Lattice Field Theory, but in other contexts of solving a PDE it means that the *position* of the boundary is unknown, and is found as part of the solution. A classical physics example would be heat transfer where there is a phase change (e.g. melting a block of ice that is surrounded by water) where the position of boundary between the solid and liquid phases is unknown, and also the position changes with time as the material melts or freezes.